# Need help create new array from some array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Please help me below problem:

I have three arrays:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
        array(2) {
            ["name"]=>string(1) "A",
            ["location"]=>string(9) "first loc"
        }
    [1]=>
        array(2) {
            ["name"]=>string(1) "A",
            ["location"]=>string(9) "second loc"
    }
    [2]=>
        array(2) {
            ["name"]=>string(1) "B",
            ["location"]=>string(9) "third loc"
    }
}
```

Two first arrays have same key and value.

Please help me to create a new array in PHP from three above as below:

```
array(2) {
    [0] => 
        array(1) {
            ["A"] => 
                 array(2) {
                      [0]=> string(9) "first loc",
                      [1]=> string(9) "second loc"
              }
          },
    [1] => 
        array(1) {
            ["B"] => 
                array(1) {
                    [0]=> string(9) "third loc"
                }
           }
}
```

Comment: Are you ok with `array(2) { ['A'] => array, ['B'] => array }`?

Comment: @PriyeshKumar Yes. Can you help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
// sample data to work on
$a = array(
    0=> array(
        "name"=>  "A",
        "location"=>"0 loc"
    ),
    1=> array(
        "name"=>  "A",
        "location"=>"1 loc"
    ),
    2=> array(
        "name"=>"B",
        "location"=>"2 loc"
    ),
    3=> array(
        "name"=>"B",
        "location"=>"3 loc"
    ),
    4=> array(
        "name"=>"A",
        "location"=>"4 loc"
    ),
    5=> array(
        "name"=>"B",
        "location"=>"5 loc"
    )
);

echo '<pre>';

$b = array();

foreach($a as $v) {

    if( isset( $b[ $v['name'] ] )) {
        // If 'A', 'B', .. so on key already exist, push this item's location
        array_push( $b[ $v['name'] ], $v['location'] ) ;
    } else {
        // Create new key
        $b[ $v['name'] ] = array($v['location']); 
    }
}
print_r($b);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 loc
            [1] => 1 loc
            [2] => 4 loc
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2 loc
            [1] => 3 loc
            [2] => 5 loc
        )

)
```

Comment: Work perfect. Thank you so much.